# Upload image in selenium C# hidden object

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hidden

I am not able to upload image:
The code is:

```
<div class="divFile">
<div id="FileUploaddiv" style="height: 70px; cursor: pointer;">
<div style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: inherit; height: inherit;" class="mf_upload_m">
```

```
<div style="position: absolute; text-align: center; z-index: 1; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; font-size: 13px;" class="mf_upload_ins">
<div class="FileHeading">Select File</div><i class="icon-file-alt icon-2" style="margin-top: 3px;"></i></div></div></div>

<div id="uploaded" style=""></div>
<span style="display: none;" class="reqFile error span2">Please Select File</span>

<input id="hdnParentID" name="hdnParentID" type="hidden">
<input id="hdnDocID" name="hdnDocID" value="0" type="hidden">
<input id="hdnDocFolderID" name="hdnDocFolderID" value="40520" type="hidden">
<input id="hddnIsEdit" name="hddnIsEdit" value="1" type="hidden">
</div>
<div class="divFileName hide"></div>
```

Code for upload:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='mf_file_FileUploaddiv']")).SendKeys("C:\\Users\\Y.P.Singh\\Desktop\\ETS.txt");
```

The code executes but the file is not getting uploaded.Also, No Error is coming.

Comment: Adding XPath of this code line:

<input style="position: relative; text-align: right; opacity: 0; z-index: 2; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;" class="file" name="mf_file_FileUploaddiv" id="mf_file_FileUploaddiv" type="file">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your Help without which I will not be able able to solve this issue. I have solved this using your technique and mixed it with something that I researched on the net.

I have imported System.Windows.Forms; and then used this Code to

```
IWebElement checkbx = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input#mf_file_FileUploaddiv.file"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions = actions.MoveToElement(checkbx);
actions = actions.Click();
actions.Build().Perform();
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("C:\\Users\\Y.P.Singh\\Desktop\\ETS.txt");
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@value='SAVE']")).Click();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just like in real life, after you input some text, you need to submit it.**

My guess is that you need to apply either one of the three options below:

- Add `.click()` after `SendKeys(...)`
- Add `.submit()` after `SendKeys(...)`
- Find the 'Upload File' button and click that element instead

If you provide the URL of the web-page which you are attempting to automate, then I might be able to give you the exact solution.

### UPDATE:

OK, I understand your problem now.

First, change `SendKeys(...)` to `Click()`.

Then, use `Actions` in order to type the name of the input file and to open it.

The code below is in Java (I am guessing that it should be pretty similar in C#):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions = actions.sendKeys(fileName);
actions = actions.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
actions.build().perform();
```

Then, wait until the file-upload process completes:

```
while (!driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='PRO0']")).equals("100%"))
    Thread.sleep(100);
```

Finally, click the 'Save' button using any of the following options:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@value='SAVE']")).click();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@innerHTML='SAVE']")).click();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='btn btn-primary btnSaveFile']")).click();
```

Comment: http://app.yourprocs.com/home/logingoogle?y=AF23BC     Click Login using Google (yatindra.qa@gmail.com password- testing12) --> Click on PROJECTS tab --> open the project from list - -> Click on Documents Tab --> open the folder - -> Click on "Add File" present at the Top --> To Upload the file in place where "Select file" is written.

I have code for every other step, only i am not able to upload image in "Select file"

Comment: Answer updated (I suggest that you change your passwords after asserting that the suggested solution is working correctly).

Comment: Hi barak, Thanks for answering. It looks the code is for clicking "SAVE" Button .However,  i want to upload image. The button for uploading image is there in top right corner where "select file" is written.

Comment: Hi. Doesn't your call to `SendKeys` cause the image to be uploaded?

Comment: i have used SendKeys, but the file is not getting uploaded. When i use .Click(); in the same Xpath, a file upload window opens to select the path.

Comment: In this code you have not added step for moving to the element in which we need to sendKeys. I am not sure how to add that to this code.

Comment: I wrote "First, change SendKeys(...) to Click()." in order to open the dialog box. Besides, even if it doesn't work for some reason, according to what you've previously mentioned, you already know how to open this dialog box, so you can continue from that point and use the `Actions` class as described in the answer...