# How can I upload a image with Selenium + PhantomJS?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm trying to upload an image to a website with Selenium + PhantomJS, but it fails.

I tried (I'm already on the page):

```
IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
var add_img = driver.FindElement(By.Id("image_upload_button"));
var image = add_img.FindElement(By.Name("file"));

Console.WriteLine("IMG: " + imagem.GetAttribute("type")); //Output: file 
String convert = "C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\myimage.jpg"; //Path
image.SendKeys(convert);
```

The HTML from the button to upload the image:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" name="file" style="height: 72px; position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 118px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;"/>
```

How can I do that?

> Error: Overload 60 secounds..

How can I do it?

Comment: Does this help: [Upload image in selenium C# hidden object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361203/upload-image-in-selenium-c-sharp-hidden-object)

Comment: I tried to do, but I get an error while trying to make actions.Build().Perform().

Comment: Ohh FINALLY I SOLVE THE PROBLEM. Just need to use that. ((PhantomJSDriver)driver).executePhantomJS("var page = this; page.uploadFile('input[type=file]', '/path/to/file');");

Comment: You can write up your own answer and accept it afterwards.